# What can be the time complexity of this code?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

i am kind of confuse in this i know in outer loop if i < n and in inner loop if j < i then the complexity will be O(n^2) but if we increase the limit from n and i respectively to n^2 and i^2 does the complexity doubles like O(n^4) or does it becomes cubic O(n^3) ?

```
   for(long i = 1; i < n*n; i++)
                {
                    for(long j = 1; j < i * i; j++)
                    {
                      //some code  
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `//some code` takes `O(1)` operations, the time complexity is `O(n^6)`. Since the inner loop takes `i^2 - 1` iterations, you can use the sum of squares formula (or equivalently use Wolfram alpha) to get

[image: sum]

Comment: does the outer loop iterates n^2  time or does it iterates (n^2 - 1) times like inner loop?

Comment: @zimba n^2 - 1, but it doesn't affect the asymptotic complexity